# The remote event receiver callout failed. Details: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, iis, azure

I want to host some Remote Event Receivers inside my Local machine to be able to test/ebug them. so i follow this procedure on how i can create low trusted Apps and host them on local IIs

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-Procedure-to-Create-a-Low-Trust-Provider-Hosted-App-for-Office-365-and-Host-the-AppWeb-in-Local-IIS

now the above link is showing how to host Apps in general, not RER specifically.
so i follow the exact steps on the link, but when i add my RER addin inside my site collection,i got this error:-

> The remote event receiver callout failed. Details: Could not establish
>   trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority
>   'localhost'

as shown in this picture:-

[image]

so can anyone advice what could be causing this?

second point, now if i can not have my RER hosted locally. Then what i was trying to do is to find a way to be ale to debug my RER code, without using Azure service bus.. so the question is if hosting RER will not work locally & i do not have an Azure service bus,then what is the appraoch i can follow to be able to debug and test RER for my sharepoint online sites?